# найти количество элементов массива равных переменной с#

Tags: c#, массивы

Мне нужно сравнить переменную с данными массива и выявить количество совпадений, но я не понимаю как

Comment: сравниваете в цикле. при совпадении увеличиваете значение счётчика на единицу. по окончании цикла выводите значение счётчика.

Comment: Уточните, какой тип переменной и какой массив у вас

Comment: `array.Count(x => x == number)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<Ваш тип данных>[] arr = ...;
<Ваш тип данных> seek = ...;
int count = 0;
foreach (var item in arr)
{
    if (item == seek)
        count++;
}
```